# C# Permanently Add and Save item to combobox

Tags: c#, winforms

everybody!

I have collection of items in combobox's properties. And I want to add new item in my combobox by writing text in combobox and then use button event:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbx_unix_dir.Items.Add(cbx_unix_dir.Text);
    }
```

But in next time of starting my programm - my added item doesn't exist in combobox. What do I wrong? I need all added items have been saved in my combobox for ever. May be problem in method InitializeComponents()? May be I have to add event before it?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to approach this differently, loading a set of additional combo box settings from the application settings helper and adding them to the combobox, or loading them from a file, currently you add it to the combobox, but its never saved or persisted as it is not added to the initialisation code.

Comment: Ali Adlavaran, thanks. But how I can add cboCollection in Settings?

Comment: comment on his answer, but you would add a list of strings or similar

Comment: If two people on different computers run the app, and the first person adds an item to the combobox, do you expect the second person to be able to see it?

Answer (score 2):

`ComboBox` has no functionality to save and reload items.

You may store items into [`.NET Settings file`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx) on closing window and reload them on loading form:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Settings.Default.cboCollection != null)
            this.cbx_unix_dir.Items.AddRange(Settings.Default.cboCollection.ToArray());
    }


    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList arraylist = new ArrayList(this.cbx_unix_dir.Items);
        Settings.Default.cboCollection = arraylist;
        Settings.Default.Save();
    }

    //A button to add items to the ComboBox
    private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cbx_unix_dir.Items.Add(cbx_unix_dir.Text);
    }
```